# I want to scale the sprite 8x with padding between pixels

Tags: imagemagick

There is a small sprite:

```
# mario sprite in base64 writing to file:
magick 'inline:data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAO
xAGVKw4bAAAA00lEQVQ4ja1UwRGDMAyTe7zLJmWUzMoodBO6gHmkhsRWcukVvYID
kiKbiKoqbsTjTjIAmLq7IvXzwGHahJ5sUKBJKKhf3rcVAPB8pZ5BTihyEcxLomuD
Fxhqyryk06WtDZ93LSB+bMqYvBtPBsQYA2FP3YPl2XUIAIpcsCZ5eRM18slvALyL
CoFAu5EApCn7tsbx+hY0U55llmkYG7NefuhzKAVFUv1Mm8L+EgKWa5zDQbIWqiNn
riuvID8g1r4c2Hi6Ghvg6sg/mqEIDv+9v2+/sQ8vtmAvY/Wf0QAAAABJRU5ErkJg
gg==' mario.png
```

I want to scale it 8x:

```
convert -scale 800%  -quality 100 mario.png mario-big.png
```

But scale with padding between pixels. To have an indent of 1 pixel between four adjacent eight times larger pixels. Or overlay a grid over the enlarged image.

How can I do this, please tell me?

Example:

[image: mario.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I'm not sure how to change the 2px spacing to 1px in my original answer. Here's another method which we can probably speed up and improve if it gets the results you want. I'm using my image below as it's a an easier size to see, but you can adjust the numbers to match your own image. I am also using the *"wrong"* colours so you can see where each one ends up, but again, you can change my mad colours to white:

- Chop into rows, each row being 50px tall
- Iterate over rows, chopping each into 50px wide chunks and recombining with 1px yellow spacing
- Smush the new rows together vertically with 1px cyan  spacing

The code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Chop into rows, each row being 50px tall
magick artistic-swirl.jpg -crop x50 row-%02d.png

# Iterate over rows, chopping each into 50px wide chunks and recombining with 1px spacing
for f in row-*png ; do
   echo $f
   magick "$f" -crop 50x -background yellow +smush 1 "$f"
done

# Smush the new rows together vertically with 1px spacing
magick row-*png -background cyan -smush 1 result.png
```

[image]

---

Note that `+smush N` joins images **side-by-side** with `N` px spacing in the background colour, but that `-smush N` joins images **above-and-below** with `N` px spacing.

---

Here's what I get applying that to your image:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Chop into rows, each row being 50px tall
magick mario.png -scale 800%  -crop x8 row-%02d.png

# Iterate over rows, chopping each into 50px wide chunks and recombining with 1px spacing
for f in row-*png ; do
   echo $f
   magick "$f" -crop 8x -background yellow +smush 1 "$f"
done

# Smush the new rows together vertically with 1px spacing
magick row-*png -background cyan -smush 1 -bordercolor blue -border 1 result.png
```

[image]

---

**Original Answer**

Not at a computer to test, but if you scale your image up to the correct size as you are currently doing, you should then be able to crop the image into tens/hundreds of individual 8x8 images and pipe them to a `montage` command to lay them out on a white background with a 1px spacing between all the individual 8x8 blocks.

Something like:

```
magick 'inline:data:...' -scale 800% -crop 8x8 miff:- | magick montage -background white -geometry +1+1 -tile Nx miff:- result.png
```

where `N` is the number of 8x8 blocks you want in each row.

---

Note that `miff:-` is an **ImageMagick** internal lossless transmission format.

---

Back at a computer, I'll do something similar with this image:

[image]

```
magick artistic-swirl.jpg -scale 500x500 -crop 50x50 miff:- | magick montage -background yellow -geometry +5+5 -tile 10x miff:- result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I set N= 20. Imagemagick can't N self calculation??

However, the spacings get 2 pixels this way, not 1. 
http://0x0.st/oplx.png
Can anything be done about this?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!
If I change both colors to white, then the image becomes black and white. If I leave at least one color not white, then ok. I don't understand why.
screenshot: http://0x0.st/op0a.png

Comment: I have added my code and results when applied to your Mario image. Not sure what's going on - maybe you have an old IM version. I am using v7.1

Comment: I am also using IM v7.1 manjaro linux.
But if I use white, then the colors disappear like in the screenshot above.
I decorated this bug by changing the white color to #fffffe. But why this is happening - I really do not understand.
my last inline edition:
magick mario-big.png -crop x8 mario-row-%02d.png ; for f in mario-row-*png ; do echo $f; magick "$f" -crop 8x -background "#fffffe" +smush 1 "$f"; done ; magick mario-row-*png -background "#fffffe" -smush 1 JPG:- | display ; rm mario-row-*.png

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach, how about [using `-fx`](https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php) to make a grid? For example:

```
convert -size 64x64 canvas: -fx "i % 9 == 0 | j % 9 == 0" x.png
```

Will set a pixel white when either the column (that's `i`) or row number (that's `j`) is on a multiple of 9. I see:

[image]

Now using Mark's suggestion, just expand your sprite by 9 with nearest neighbor, then use a ternary operator to pick either the image (image pixels are `u`) or white (1.0):

```
convert mario.png \
    -scale 900% \
    -fx "(i % 9 == 0 | j % 9 == 0) ? 1.0 : u" \
    result.png
```

With this test image:

[image]

I see:

[image]

It'll work for any size image, though it'll be pretty slow if the image is large.

Comment: Good thinking!!!

Comment: Hi! Thanx you. -fx is interest function. I really don't understand how she does it. hard documentation...  ( https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php)   complex mathematics :(
How to overlay the resulting file on the enlarged sprite image? I'm afraid I won't do it myself. I previously tried to use file image as a background, but it did not work.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to overlay. You can use a ternary operator, and return white (i.e. 1) if x or y coordinate is a multiple of 9, else return the original image - which **ImageMagick** refers to as `u` (the second being `v` by the way). So `magick mario.png -scale 800% -fx "(i % 9 == 0 | j % 9 == 0) ? 1.0 : u" result.png`

Comment: If you wanted to build a black and white grid separately and composite it on top, choosing the lighter pixel at each location `magick mario.png -scale 800% \( +clone -colorspace gray -fx "(i % 9 == 0 | j % 9 == 0) ? 1.0 : 0" \) -compose lighten -composite result.png`

Comment: Very interesting solution, but it's hard to understand how it works?    

``-scale 800%`` too small for original scaled files, mesh stacks. The value ``900`` is correct. Other than Mario, I tried a variant with a different image 50x50 px:

Comment: I added a complete example, following Mark's suggestion.